# Strange chirping sound appeared after firmware upgrade

Tags: creality-ender-3, firmware

I got 4.2.7 "silent" motherboard and plugged it into my Creality Ender. It worked well except it didn't recognize my (old) BLTouch device. I tried to download firmware from official site, and it worked, but strande chirping sound started to come out of printer.

Probably I have chosen incorrect firmware. Although now I can't choose correct one. Is there any explanation of this sound?

Answer (score 1):

It was because of incorrect firmware.

Previously I was using BLTouch 3.1 with Creality MD 1.1.4. This MB required to plug special small adapter board between MB and display, having BLTouch connected to this adapter board.

When I bought new MB 4.2.7 I found it had seprate socket for BLTouch. I found [manual in the Internet about how to connect BLTouch](https://tutorial.cytron.io/2021/10/19/bltouch-installation-for-ender-3-with-32-bit-v4-2-2-board/) to this socket, which appeared to be correct.

Then I started to choose firmware and found there three versions of it: without adapter board, with adapter board, and with both adapter board and filament detector. I thought that this choice depends on BLTouch version and chosen one "with adapter board" because mine was with it initially and this was a mistake.

Apparently, this firmware was sending BLTouch control signal towards display wires and adapter board was filtering it and sendinf to BLTouch. In my case there was no adapter board and a signal, which was intended to control BLTouch, was reaching display circuit and causing it make weird sound.

Once I downloaded firmware version without adapter board the sound disappeared.